# How to convolve a function with delta function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

as we know that another function convolve with delta function,  the output will same as the function itself, for example

> f(n) * δ(n) = f(n)

For example

```
n=-10:10;
h=[n>=0];
i=[(n-4)>=0];
f=h-i;
```

I get the function `f(n)`, but how should I code the `δ(n)` in order to  get a stem plot of `f(n) * δ(n)` ?

One more question, if we convolve one function itself repeatedly, what actually is happening? I try doing some chain convolution in Matlab like `conv(conv(f,f,'same'),f,'same');`, the stem plot are varying but i cant figure out the reason. 
Please assist, thank you.

Comment: Dirac delta function is used just in analytical math. The definition is `δ(x)=Inf` if `x=0` and `δ(x)=0` otherwise. Moreover, `integral(δ(x),-Inf,Inf)=1`. Thus your `f(n) * δ(n) = f(n)` is incorrect! Also, you can approximate it using limits, for example `δ(x)=a/(a^2+x^2)/pi` if `a→0` (or very very small) .

Comment: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/impulse.html may be useful

Comment: @AlexanderKorovin `δ(0)=Inf` and `δ(x)=0` otherwise is NOT the definition of the function. There is no clear definition of the function. It is just stated that its infinitisimal small and the integration is 1. There are easily functions that obey this and have `δ(0)=0`. And `f(n) * δ(n) = f(n)` is correct, as long as * is the convolution (as defined) and not the replacement for the multiplier dot.

Comment: @KamiKaze you can see the definition of the Dirac delta function for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function). Perhaps, the author of the question meant [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta). Thus, `f(n) * δ(0) = f(n)` or `f(n') * δ(n-n') = f(n)`.

Comment: @AlexanderKorovin from your Wikipedia link: `he Dirac delta can be loosely thought of` `This is merely a heuristic characterization. The Dirac delta is not a function in the traditional sense as no function defined on the real numbers has these properties.` It is not defined to be this way. It the general imagination of it, but it is NOT the definition.

Comment: @KamiKaze, you are right. As I wrote: "Dirac delta function is used just in analytical math". But using it definition with limits (see my first comment) you can coding it.

Comment: A common way to visualize it is a very small very high triangle function (impulse weight = 1) but nothing in the definition hinders you to put two triangles next to each other with the middle point being 0. If you then "press it together" and keep the impulse weight, you also have a valid way to "build" it. And regarding your last comment. Yes that's how nearly everyone works with it I guess, I just wanted to make clear that it not defined that way.

Comment: @KamiKaze, there are a lot of possibilities to present the Dirac delta function numerically (approximatelly). See "Autres exemples" subsection [here](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_de_Dirac)

Comment: Just for clarification here, after 7 or so years: δ(x)=Inf does not figure in the definition of the Dirac delta function. It is a consequence, but it’s not the definition. The definition says the integral is 1 and the function is 0 everywhere except at the origin. In the discrete world, this definition corresponds to the Kronecker delta, which has the same function in the discrete convolution as the continuous Dirac delta in the continuous convolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In discrete math the impulse is `δ(0) = 1`, `δ(n) = 0` for `n != 0`.

If you convolve a function with itself, you just do exactly that. There is nothing special about it.

Convolve it with the mirrored(at the y-axis) function of itself would be an auto-correlation.

Answer (score 0):

Convolution with delta shifts input by k-1 places:

```
delta=zeros(n); delta(k)=1 %k'th canonical basis vector
```

In higher dimensions, delta(ind(1),ind(2),..)=1

```
delta=zeros(dims); delta(num2cell(inds){:})=1 %canonical basis of matrices
```

Repeated convolution of the probability distribution of a random variable X results in the probability distribution of the sum of 'n' indpendent identically distributed copies X1+X2+..+Xn.

Comment: Convolution with delta doesn’t change the input. As OP already said, f(n) * δ(n) = f(n). If you see a shift, you didn’t define the delta correctly.